# How to toggle between background images using input type = checkbox that is nested within label class="..."?

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox, toggle

I cannot get my alternate background-image to be toggled to when I click on my toggle checkbox 'button'. I inputted my relevant code into CodePen and it was able to toggle correctly; however, when I copy it into my text editor (as shown in the code below, it fails to even get to the alert statement nested within this line: "$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){".

I followed "https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp" to create the switch; however, unclear as to why they nested input into the label tag, or why they included a span tag. Any help or explanation would be greatly appreciated.

HTML (part of my code):

```
<label class="switch">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

CSS (part of my code):

```
body {
  background-image: url(background.png);
  ...
}

/* the box around the slider */
.switch {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  top: 37px;
  left: 40px;
}

/* hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT (all of my code):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    alert("got here");
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
       $('body').css("background-image", "url(background-dark.png)");  
    }
    else if($(this).is(":not(:checked)")){
       $('body').css("background-image", "url(background1.png)");
    }
});
```

I expected the background image to change to 'background-dark.png' every time I clicked the toggle switch; however, nothing seems to happen when I repeatedly click on the toggle switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your switch works fine. The included `span` is there to replace HTML's original checkbox. `Label` is used to show description of an `input` element. Currently, however, they have not included any text with it and are using it as a wrapper to position and size the checkbox.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
       $('body').css("background-image", "url(https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg)");  
    }
    else if($(this).is(":not(:checked)")){
       $('body').css("background-image", "url(https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg)");
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg);
}

/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Cray, thanks for your input. I added the script you included and even tried to use your particular images; however, when I load/preview the html file on my computer and I use the toggle switch, the background image still does not change. I tried to see what the problem was by adding an alert statement into my JS file as seen below..

$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
       alert("here");
       ...
});

however, my code never seems to reach the statement. I linked my javascript file as such: <script src="main.js"></script>

Comment: Your original post is missing some of the CSS. Do you even have the switch button the way my snippet has? Other than that does the javascript file load or is it getting 404 error? Must be something missing or wrong in configuration as the almost same code works in my snippet.

Comment: I am now able to toggle between the two photos that you use; however, when I plug in my .png file into the 'background-image: url(background.png)' I am unable to toggle the photo. Am I allowed to have a .png file saved to the same folder as the html file and can I access it through the url() method? Thanks!

Comment: for reference..

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
      if($(this).is(":checked")){
         $('body').css("background-image", "url(background-dark.png)");  
      }
      else if($(this).is(":not(:checked)")){
         $('body').css("background-image", "url(background.png)");
      }
  });
});

Comment: So you are getting a 404 error in browser console for the image? [How relative paths work](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp). And yes, you can have images in any folder that can be accessed and use it in `url()`.

Comment: I was but it's fixed now. Thank you for all your help! (:

Comment: No problem, you can mark the question as answered then.